# How to use localStorage?

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

The admin panel of my local experiment has a "nightmode" switch that -after turning it on- changes the admin panel regular styles into the nightmode styles. Below is a simplified version of the script. How do I properly use the `localStorage` JavaScript property, to store the current nightmode setting?

```
function nightmode() {
    let nbtn = document.getElementById("nightmode");
    let head = document.getElementById("header");
    let cont = document.getElementById("content");
    
    cont.classList.toggle("nightmode");
    
    if(nbtn.innerHTML === "<span><i class=\"fa fa-sun-o\"></i></span>") {
        nbtn.innerHTML = "<span><i class=\"fa fa-moon-o\"></i></span>";
        head.style.cssText = "background-color:black; border-color:black; box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;";
    } else {
        nbtn.innerHTML = "<span><i class=\"fa fa-sun-o\"></i></span>";
        head.style.cssText = "background-color:none; border-color:none; box-shadow:none;";
    }
}
```

I've had no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `localStorage.setItem('nightMode', true);` to set a key value pair.

You can use `localStorage.getItem(nightMode);` to get the value of the key.
You can store it into a variable with `const nightModeBool  = localStorage.getItem('nightMode');`
To remove an item from Local Storage, use `localStorage.removeItem('nightMode');`
To clear the Local Storage use `localStorage.clear();`

The cookies you set cannot be accessed from another website or URL, it can only be accessed from the site the cookie is set.

More Details : [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)